# how to remove a certain type of character in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file , A.csv (sep=",") :

```
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565907,E11,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565919,A10,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565931,E01,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
```

And I want to remove the "0" of the column 4 BUT ONLY for number [1-9] , i.e if data are "B01" I want "B1" but if data are "B10" I want it to stay "B10". So in my example it would be :

```
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565907,E11,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565919,A10,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
07/15/20  19:10:03,TAQPATH-AB275013338-MOL_0003,2060565931,E1,Patient,VALID,SARS-CoV-2 Not Detected,REPORT
```

I've done :

```
awk -F ","  'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {sub("0", "", $4); print}' A.csv > B.csv
```

but it remove ALL the "0", can someone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You **could** change `sub("0","",$4)` to `sub(/0$/,RS,$4); sub(/0/,"",$4); sub(RS,0,$4)` but for this particular case I prefer @Inian's approach of separating the numeric part and adding zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to backup the first character and replace the part containing leading `0` using `sub()`

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } $4 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]/ { lead = substr($4, 1, 1); sub ("^[[:alpha:]]0*", lead, $4) }1' file
```

The initial condition `$4 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]/` marks only those lines whose `$4` starts with a alphabet. We only extract the first digit on those lines using `substr()` function and then using `sub()` replace from beginning and all leading zeros and substitute that pattern with the first character alone.

Another way would be to force convert the part after the first alphabet to numeric part by doing `+0`, which will strip off the leading zeros

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } $4 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]/ && NR > 1 { $4 = substr($4, 1, 1) "" substr($4, 2)+0 }1' file
```

Comment: Wow it's a clever answer, thanks !